# Adding semi-transparent images as textures in Scenekit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

When I add a semi-transparent image ([sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6jpF.png)) as a texture for a SCNNode, how can I specify a color attribute for the node where the image is transparent. Since I am able to specify either color or image as a material property, I am unable to specify the color value to the node. Is there a way to specify both color and image for the material property or is there a workaround to this problem.

Comment: You can find a working example of doing this with OpenGL under iOS here, the same approach could be adapted to your SceneKit impl. http://www.modejong.com/blog/post7_load_opengl_textures_with_alpha_channel_on_ios

Answer (score 5):

If you are assigning the image to the `contents` of the `transparent` material property, you can change the materials `transparencyMode` to be either `.AOne` or `.RGBZero`.

- `.AOne` means that transparency is derived from the images alpha channel.
- `.RGBZero` means that transparency is derived from the luminance (the total red, green, and blue) in the image.

You cannot configure an arbitrary color to be treated as transparency without a custom shader.

However, from the looks of your sample image, I would think that assigning the sample image to the `transparent` material properties `contents` and using the `.AOne` transparency mode would give you the result you are looking for.

Comment: I tried assigning the sample image to `transparent` material property contents and used the `AOne` transparency mode, but it has used only the alpha value from the image and ignored the color values of the image. For example, I had done this for `SCNBox` that has been assigned a yellow color and what I got was [this image](http://i.imgur.com/76ddzPC.png), but what I want is [this](http://i.imgur.com/hhfjEYm.png)

Comment: @Krish did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Crashalot No, I haven't found a solution yet. I need to try the approach suggested by MoDJ.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this as a new answer because it's different from the other answer.

---

Based on your comment, I understand that you want to want to use an image with transparency as the diffuse content of a material, but use a background color wherever the image is transparent. In other words, you won't to use [a composite of the image *over* a color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) as the diffuse contents.

## Using UIImage

There are a few different ways you can achieve this composited image. The easiest and likely most familiar solution is to create a new UIImage that draws the image over the color. This new image will have the same size and scale as your image, but can be opaque since it has a solid background color.

```
func imageByComposing(image: UIImage, over color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, true, image.scale)
    defer {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }

    let imageRect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: image.size)
    // fill with background color
    color.set()
    UIRectFill(imageRect)
    // draw image on top
    image.drawInRect(imageRect)

    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
}
```

Using this image as the contents of the diffuse material property will give you the effect that you're after.

## Using Shader Modifiers

If you find yourself having to change the color very frequently (possibly animating it), you could also use custom shaders or shader modifiers to composite the image over the color.

In that case, you want to composite the image **A** **over** the color **B**, so that the output color (C<sub>O</sub>) is:

C<sub>O</sub> = C<sub>A</sub> + C<sub>B</sub> * (1 - ɑ<sub>A</sub>)

By passing the image as the diffuse contents, and assigning the output to the diffuse content, the expression can be simplified as:

C<sub>diffuse</sub> = C<sub>diffuse</sub> + C<sub>color</sub> * (1 - ɑ<sub>diffuse</sub>) 
C<sub>diffuse</sub> += C<sub>color</sub> * (1 - ɑ<sub>diffuse</sub>)

Generally the output alpha would depend on the alpha of A and B, but since B (the color) is opaque (1), the output alpha is also 1.

This can be written as a small shader modifier. Since the motivation for this solutions was to be able to change the color, the color is created as a uniform variable which can be updated in code.

```
// Define a color that can be set/changed from code
uniform vec3 backgroundColor;
#pragma body
// Composit A (the image) over B (the color):
//  output = image + color * (1-alpha_image)
float alpha = _surface.diffuse.a;
_surface.diffuse.rgb += backgroundColor * (1.0 - alpha);
// make fully opaque (since the color is fully opaque)
_surface.diffuse.a = 1.0;
```

This shader modifier would then be read from the file, and set in the materials shader modifier dictionary

```
enum ShaderLoadingError: ErrorType {
    case FileNotFound, FailedToLoad
}

func shaderModifier(named shaderName: String, fileExtension: String = "glsl") throws -> String {
    guard let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(shaderName, withExtension: fileExtension) else {
        throw ShaderLoadingError.FileNotFound
    }

    do {
        return try String(contentsOfURL: url)
    } catch {
        throw ShaderLoadingError.FailedToLoad
    }
}

// later, in the code that configures the material ...

do {
    let modifier = try shaderModifier(named: "Composit") // the name of the shader modifier file (assuming 'glsl' file extension) 
    theMaterial.shaderModifiers = [SCNShaderModifierEntryPointSurface: modifier]
} catch {
    // Handle the error here
    print(error)
}
```

You would then be able to change the color by setting a new value for the "backgroundColor" of the material. Note that there is no initial value, so one would have to be set.

```
let backgroundColor = SCNVector3Make(1.0, 0.0, 0.7) // r, g, b

// Set the color components as an SCNVector3 wrapped in an NSValue
// for the same key as the name of the uniform variable in the sahder modifier
theMaterial.setValue(NSValue(SCNVector3: backgroundColor), forKey: "backgroundColor")
```

---

As you can see, the first solution is simpler and the one I would recommend if it suits your needs. The second solution is more complicated, but enabled the background color to be animated.

Comment: Another option, depending on your scene needs, might be layered geometry — for example, put your solid color on one sphere, and your transparent image on another sphere that's concentric with the other and slightly larger. See the Earth with clouds "slide" in the [WWDC14 SceneKit demo](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SceneKitWWDC2014/Introduction/Intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone comes across this in the future... for some tasks, ricksters solution is likely the easiest. In my case, I wanted to display a grid on top of an image that was mapped to a sphere. I originally composited the images into one and applied them, but over time I got more fancy and this started getting complex. So I made two spheres, one inside the other. I put the grid on the inner one and the image on the outer one and presto...

```
    let outSphereGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 20)
    outSphereGeometry.segmentCount = 100
    let outSphereMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    outSphereMaterial.diffuse.contents = topImage
    outSphereMaterial.isDoubleSided = true
    outSphereGeometry.materials = [outSphereMaterial]
    outSphere = SCNNode(geometry: outSphereGeometry)
    outSphere.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)

    let sphereGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 10)
    sphereGeometry.segmentCount = 100
    sphereMaterial.diffuse.contents = gridImage
    sphereMaterial.isDoubleSided = true
    sphereGeometry.materials = [sphereMaterial]
    sphere = SCNNode(geometry: sphereGeometry)
    sphere.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
```

I was surprised that I didn't need to set sphereMaterial.transparency, it seems to get this automatically.